# Correct way of using StackExchange.Redis in WPF Applicaition

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have implemented Stackexchange.Redis in my application to fetch data from redis db list.
On login application(WPF) creates a list and push data which gets fetched by another module(C++) over server where redis db is been created. Server modules pushes the response to a user specific list from where WPF module read data through polling every 10ms.

Following methods I have created to perform these tasks.

1. Constructor

```
      public RedisConnection()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ConnectionMultiplexer.SetFeatureFlag("preventthreadtheft", true);
                        if (_databaseRedis != null)
                            this.DatabaseRedis = _databaseRedis;
                        if (_clientSubscriptionChannnel != null)
                            this.ClientSubscriptionChannnel = _clientSubscriptionChannnel;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                }
```

2. Connect  Redis

```
       public bool CreateConnection(Hashtable ParamsHt)
        {          
            try
            {
                var settings = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(ParamsHt["RedisIP"].ToString());
                settings.ConnectRetry = 3;
                settings.ConnectTimeout = 10000;
                settings.SyncTimeout = 20000;
                connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(settings);
                if (connection.IsConnected)
                {
                    DatabaseRedis = connection.GetDatabase();
                }
                return isConnected = connection.IsConnected;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

3. Fetch data from the list

```
       private  void FetchListToProcess()
        {
            try
            {                
                IDatabase database = connection.GetDatabase();                 
                long length = database.ListLength(ConfigurationService.ListToInsertRequest + "_" + LoginID);
                if (length > 0)
                {
                    RedisValue rv = database.ListLeftPop(ConfigurationService.ListToInsertRequest+"_"+ LoginID, CommandFlags.None);
                    if (rv.HasValue)
                    {
                        database.ListRemove(LoginID, rv);
                        byte[] userObject = (byte[])rv;
                        CommonOM.MessageHeader HeaderObj = CommonBL.ByteArrayToStructure<CommonOM.MessageHeader>(userObject);
                        int MessageType = HeaderObj.messageCode;
                        if (MessageType == Convert.ToInt32(TRANSACTION_REQUEST_CODE.HEART_BEAT))
                        {   
                           delRecieveReadyRedisHearbeat delHeartbeatReciever = new delRecieveReadyRedisHearbeat(_heartbeatHelper.OnRecieveHeartbeat);
                           delHeartbeatReciever.BeginInvoke(MessageType, userObject, null, null);
                           
                        }
                        else 
                        {    
                           delRecieveReadyRedisHearbeat delHeartbeatReciever = new delRecieveReadyRedisHearbeat(_heartbeatHelper.OnRecieveHeartbeat);
                           delHeartbeatReciever.BeginInvoke(MessageType, userObject, null, null);
                          
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            delRecieveReadyRedisMessages delReady = new delRecieveReadyRedisMessages(_connectionHelper.OnReceive);
                            delReady.BeginInvoke(MessageType, userObject, null, null);
                        }                      
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException ex)
            {
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               
            }
        }
```

4. Insert Data into List

```
   public void InsertIntoList(byte[] messageToSend,bool isLoginRequest,string loginID)
        {
            try
            {
                IDatabase database = connection.GetDatabase();
                database.ListRightPush(ConfigurationService.ListToInsertRequest, messageToSend);
            }
            catch (RedisTimeoutException ex)
            {
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

After creating connection I start a System.timer  at every 10ms calls FetchListToProcess() method which checks whether any data existed in the list or not if so it fetches and process accordingly.

I am experiencing an issue where application logs RedisTimeout exception randomly:

```
Error Messg :: Timeout performing LLEN (5000ms), next: LLEN ROUTER_IEORALG9, inst: 2, qu: 0, qs: 40, aw: False, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe: 0, serverEndpoint: 192.168.37.182:8081, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: IETRD-15628-2, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=20,Free=32747,Min=8,Max=32767), v: 2.0.601.3402 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
03:29:26.93 :: Stack Trace ::    at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 2239
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\RedisBase.cs:line 54
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ListLength(RedisKey key, CommandFlags flags) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\RedisDatabase.cs:line 943
   at BL.RedisConnection.FetchListToProcess()
03:29:27.43 :: Method Name :: Redis --> RedisTimeoutException
03:29:27.43 :: Error Messg :: Timeout performing LLEN (5000ms), next: LLEN ROUTER_IEORALG9, inst: 3, qu: 0, qs: 41, aw: False, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe: 0, serverEndpoint: 192.168.37.182:8081, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: IETRD-15628-2, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=21,Free=32746,Min=8,Max=32767), v: 2.0.601.3402 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
03:29:27.43 :: Stack Trace ::    at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 2239
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\RedisBase.cs:line 54
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ListLength(RedisKey key, CommandFlags flags) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\RedisDatabase.cs:line 943
   at BL.RedisConnection.FetchListToProcess()
03:29:28.94 :: Method Name :: Redis --> RedisTimeoutException
03:29:28.94 :: Error Messg :: Timeout performing LLEN (5000ms), next: LLEN ROUTER_IEORALG9, inst: 1, qu: 0, qs: 44, aw: False, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe: 0, serverEndpoint: 192.168.37.182:8081, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: IETRD-15628-2, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=22,Free=32745,Min=8,Max=32767), v: 2.0.601.3402 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
03:29:28.94 :: Stack Trace ::    at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 2239
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\RedisBase.cs:line 54
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ListLength(RedisKey key, CommandFlags flags) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\RedisDatabase.cs:line 943
   at BL.RedisConnection.FetchListToProcess()
03:29:29.36 :: Method Name :: Redis --> RedisTimeoutException
03:29:29.36 :: Error Messg :: Timeout performing LLEN (5000ms), next: LLEN ROUTER_IEORALG9, inst: 2, qu: 0, qs: 45, aw: False, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe: 0, serverEndpoint: 192.168.37.182:8081, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: IETRD-15628-2, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=22,Free=32745,Min=8,Max=32767), v: 2.0.601.3402 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
03:29:29.36 :: Stack Trace ::    at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 2239
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\RedisBase.cs:line 54
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ListLength(RedisKey key, CommandFlags flags) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\RedisDatabase.cs:line 943
   at BL.RedisConnection.FetchListToProcess()
03:29:29.42 :: Method Name :: Redis --> RedisTimeoutException
03:29:29.42 :: Error Messg :: Timeout performing LLEN (5000ms), next: LLEN ROUTER_IEORALG9, inst: 3, qu: 0, qs: 46, aw: False, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe: 0, serverEndpoint: 192.168.37.182:8081, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: IETRD-15628-2, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=22,Free=32745,Min=8,Max=32767), v: 2.0.601.3402 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
03:29:29.42 :: Stack Trace ::    at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 2239
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\RedisBase.cs:line 54
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ListLength(RedisKey key, CommandFlags flags) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\RedisDatabase.cs:line 943
   at BL.RedisConnection.FetchListToProcess()
```

and for insert into list method as well

```
03:29:26.42 :: Method Name :: RedisConnection --> InsertIntoList
03:29:26.42 :: Error Messg :: Timeout performing RPUSH (5000ms), next: LLEN ROUTER_IEORALG9, inst: 1, qu: 0, qs: 35, aw: False, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe: 0, serverEndpoint: 192.168.37.182:8081, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: IETRD-15628-2, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=18,Free=32749,Min=8,Max=32767), v: 2.0.601.3402 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
03:29:26.42 :: Stack Trace ::    at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 2239
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\RedisBase.cs:line 54
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ListRightPush(RedisKey key, RedisValue value, When when, CommandFlags flags) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\RedisDatabase.cs:line 1004
   at BL.RedisConnection.InsertIntoList(Byte[] messageToSend, Boolean isLoginRequest, String loginID)
```

This exception stops fetching data and it goes very random for different users.. like for some it continued till 2-3 minutes for others it may stops after 30-40 seconds.
Previously it was occurring simultaneously for all connected users at same time but now happens at random time with random number of users. Around 5-10 applications connects at these redis port .
We use single list to insert data which server application reads & per connected user separate list to fetch data.

I tried reading and implementing options mentioned in the link under exception details but no luck.
Please suggest what I am doing wrong?
Is  it the implementation or anything else going wrong?

Regards,
honeyashu

Comment: @marc Gravell .. can you plese suggest

Comment: the first thing I'd look at is: `slowlog` on the server; is this perhaps genuinely reporting server blockages?